# Backing up Google Drive data in the event of a virus attack

Tags: backup, google-drive

I am moving to GDrive (Google Drive) more and more these days. Can't see myself ever leaving the cloud.

My question is about backing up of data on Google Drive. As I understand, GDrive and similar services are great in the event of a local hardware failure, because all the data is sitting on a server somewhere else.

However what is to stop a virus, even another person, from coming onto my computer and deleting everything from my GDrive folders. In that event the data will be lost forever.

Or does GDrive backup data every week or so?

That is the one thing that is making me nervous.

Answer (score 1):

**All** commercial cloud services implement disaster-recovery solutions aimed to protect the customers' files in case of local hardware or software disaster.

The problem is now to focus on the event that the user's files are accidentally or maliciously removed/altered.

Indeed, the cloud provider does implement a solution that allows system admins to recover older versions of files, but is that feature available to the customer himself too?

[Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2405957?hl=en) partially implements such feature. Policies say that in the event that files are deleted "permanently" from a user's space, they are not recoverable.

It is to understand if this is because of a commercial policy or a technical specification, i.e. "does Google really really delete/wipe files after I delete them from trash?"

### The short answer to the OP question is No

Comment: Maybe you should move to a cloud backup service that provides versioning of files. I can't suggest you one

Comment: I think that the use of "local" here is misleading. Cloud providers MAY implement DR though as they have never been tested in most cases, it is moot as to whether they would be of use. BUT any DR implemented is for THEIR data centres and doesn't protect from a virus on a users (local) machine.

Comment: Also, Google are already notorious about deleting users accounts - there is no recovery from that.

Answer (score 1):

There is **nothing** stopping a virus damaging, deleting or encrypting your GDrive data if you have the drive mounted as a network drive.

There is nothing stopping Google from deleting your data without telling you.

Unless you are careful, there isn't much stopping other people taking over your Google account and preventing access.

These are the difficulties of cloud storage. Difficulties made insurmountable if you rely on the free or cheap services that are provided to reel you in to other services. What Service Level Agreements do you have? What commercial insurance do you have? Answer: none.

If your data is important to you, it is vitally important that you keep it in multiple locations. It is also vital that you understand the difference between file storage such as DropBox, GDrive, etc. and a *backup*.

A backup is not easily deleted, it is taken automatically, it is kept in multiple locations.

All key data should be backed up. I use Crashplan. I back up to the cloud and I back up to a local PC. So I have the data in an encrypted backup on two continents.

DropBox, et-al are useful for convenience not for security or resilience.

Comment: thanks. I am getting the impression that backing up is just as necessary as it was before.

Comment: You got it! :) Unfortunately, backups are always necessary. The great thing is that you now have lots of low-cost options.